# Why does this list matcher not working as expected?

Tags: scala

I am practicing to use extractor:

```
scala> object LE {
     | def unapply[A](theList: List[A]) = 
     | if (theList.size == 0) None
     | else Some((theList.head, theList.tail))
     | }
defined module LE
```

It works for matching one element:

```
scala> List(0, 1, 2) match {
     | case head LE more => println(head, more)
     | }
(0,List(1, 2))
```

But does not appear to work for matching more than one element:

```
scala> List(0, 1, 2) match {
     | case head LE next LE more => println(head, more)
     | }
<console>:10: error: scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;
 found   : List[A]
 required: Int
```

My list extractor looks very similar to Scala's Stream extractor, which can be used like this:

```
val xs = 58 #:: 43 #:: 93 #:: Stream.empty
xs match {
  case first #:: second #:: _ => first - second
  case _ => -1
}
```

So what difference prevents my LE from being used in such a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the order of execution. For `#::`, since it ends with `:`, Scala treats it specially, associating from right to left instead of left to right (as is normal for any other operator/type, such as your `LE`). The following works as you expect:

```
scala> List(0, 1, 2) match {
     | case head LE (next LE more) => println(head, more)
     | }
(0,List(2))
```

Comment: Could you please suggest a way to modify `LE` or the matcher so that `case head LE next LE more` works?

Comment: Whups! Copied over the wrong line. Edited version should work now.